# My Application is running without any error but i am not getting gauge chart image

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class PerformanceChart : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=****;user id=***;Password=****;database=****");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            BindChart();
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string cmd = "SELECT COUNT(IF(Status='A',1,NULL))'OPEN',COUNT(IF(Status='D',1,NULL))'CLOSE', YEAR(Start_Date_Time) FROM sh_report WHERE YEAR(Start_Date_Time)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) GROUP BY YEAR(Start_Date_Time)";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    private void BindChart()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            dt = GetData();

            str.Append(@"<script type=text/javascript> google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*gauge*]});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string','YEAR(Start_Date_Time)');
            data.addColumn('number','COUNT');

            data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");

            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["YEAR(Start_Date_Time)"].ToString() + "');");
                str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["COUNT)"].ToString() + ");");
            }
            str.Append("var options = {width:600,height:300,redFrom:90,redTo:100,yellowFrom:75,yellowTo:90,minorTicks:5};");
            str.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
            str.Append("chart.draw(data,options);}");
            str.Append("</script>");
            lt.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',').Replace('*', '"');
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
}


My ASPX page code :


<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PerformanceChart.aspx.cs" Inherits="PerformanceChart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="chart_div">
    </div>
        <asp:Literal ID="lt" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Every thing is working fine but not displaying o/p can any one pls help me.
is any thing wrong in this code . i tried many ways but it's not displaying gauge chart. I am new to asp.net , i need your help thanx in advance

Comment: Do you see any chart values in your page's view source?

Comment: it's not showing any chart values in pages source

Comment: can you please explain some more briefly ....

Comment: Sure. Prior to anything being written to your output statement you should verify via breakpoints if your data is successfully being pulled from the database or of your catch statement is firing.  If you are new to setting breakpoints check out this tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: Thanx for ur reply. I v'll check it now

Comment: it's showing like this       ----- Build started: Project: Performance_Gauge, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/'.

Validation Complete
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: that is a successful build. For debugging purposes you will need break points to see the value of certain variables at different points within your code.  What you are interested in is setting a red dot beside "DataTable dt = new DataTable();" and then clicking F5. This will run your code to the breakpoint. You cloud then mouse over variables and see their values.

Comment: still it's not displaying chart but it's showing chart values in page source

Comment: @Charles can you pls see  MySQl query weather its correct or wrong

Comment: If the chart values are being displayed in the page source, their might be a problem with the content you are sending to the Google. Please include the page source information.